# How can we get all $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$s_2(n)$ denotes the sum of the standard base-2 digits of $n$.

When $k=2^m$, we have $s_2(nk)=s_2(n)$.

Can we find $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$?

**UPD:** Thanks to marty cohen, who found $n=13,k=5,nk=65$, which $s_2(nk)=2,s_2(n)=3$. So, another question comes: how can we get **all** $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$,which $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

65=13*5.

More generally,
since
$a^{2k+1}+1
=(a+1)\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^i a^i
$,
here is an infinite class
of solutions:

For
$j \ge 1$,
$k \ge 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
2^{j(2k+1)}+1
&=(2^j)^{2k+1}+1\\
&=(2^j+1)\sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-1)^i 2^{ij}\\
&=(2^j+1)\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{k} ( 2^{2ij}-2^{(2i-1)j})\right)\\
&=(2^j+1)\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{(2i-1)j}( 2^{j}-1)\right)\\
&=(2^j+1)\left(1+( 2^{j}-1)\sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{(2i-1)j}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

My example is
$j=2, k=1$,
where
$2^6+1
=(2^2+1)(1+3(2^2))
=5\cdot 13
$.

For $k=1$,
this is
$2^{3j+1}+1
=(2^j+1)(1+(2^j-1)2^j)
$
and
$1+(2^j-1)2^j$ has
$j+1$ ones.

A computer search
might suggest other classes of
solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! And have you ever thought about: how can we get all $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$?

Comment: I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Assume $k$ is odd, we can construct $n=2^{2m}-2^{m}-1$ for which $m=\lfloor log_2(k)\rfloor +1$.